# Pass Data from Thymeleaf to Spring Boot Controller, for redirection purposes

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to implement [this](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) tutorial but I don't understand what `message/list` means. I've created a Spring Boot app that consumes another API, fetches it's data as JSON format and stores them in PostgreSQL database.

One of the columns in my DB are URL's that came from that API. I am displaying them at frontend in HTML using Thymeleaf. My goal is to create a frontend of URLs that when users click them, will redirect them at the appropriate website outside of my application.

I've to combine the data transfer from Thymeleaf back to controller and redirection from the controller to the outside of my application at the same time.

Is there any possibility to do this? Below I am showing you my frontend code and below that the controller that I tried to implement, with no success since it's giving me.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for key 'rate.news_link'
```

**FrontEnd**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:https="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/db.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>


</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos" target="_blank">Github</a></li>
</ul>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Cryptocurrency News</h1>
    </div>

</main>
    <!--Display DB contents on HTML and Thymeleaf-->

    <div class="container text-center" id="tasksDiv">
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>News Provider Name</th>
                    <th>News Link</th>
                    <th>Related Image</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="rate: ${rates}">
                        <td th:text="${rate.news_provider_name}"> </td>
                        <td>
                            <a
                                    href="#"
                                    th:href="${rate.news_link}"
                                    th:text="${rate.HEADLINE}">
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td> <img th:src="${rate.related_image}" alt="error displaying image"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String redirect() {
        return "redirect:/${rate.news_link}";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are not passing any variables so you cannot use them the tutorial you are following is using constant values.
If you want to use variables you can do that by taking input using `@PathVariable` or `@RequestParam` depending on your need or choice.
If you don't know spring boot or learning it, I recommend you first learn spring boot web(to make the rest  APIs) and then move to  Spring MVC.

Comment: indeed, I am learning it from scratch. This code is part of my MSc thesis and I can't figure a way to do this. At least I am happy for the efforts done so far for the whole project. I searched and found [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-request-parameters). Should I follow it?

Comment: yes, this is  much better